# Not able to work with Miniconda on Windows 10

Tags: python, pandas, miniconda

I have been trying to use a Conda Environment and I am working with Python 3.10.2. I want to install Pandas and SciPy through Miniconda. I downloaded it but when I tried running `conda install pandas` on the command prompt it says that "Conda is not recognised as an internal or an external command, a program or a batch file'. What could have gone wrong?
Can you also suggest an alternate way to download Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda probably wasn't added as a path variable. Locate the conda.exe [add it to the path](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/).

> Can you also suggest an alternate way to download Pandas?

You could use [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/):

```
pip install pandas
```